# Netbeans Resource Management for Java EE application

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, netbeans-7

I am trying to add resources to my Java Web Application in Netbeans.

The process that I followed is

1. Right Click on the project and create a New Folder "MyResources"
2. After that I added my audio file , "a.mp3".

Now, when I Run the project, I don't see that resources in Apache Tomcat Directory i.e work directory . Nor do I see it in bin folder.

Any pointer to add resources to a web application.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:
Right click on the project | `Properties...` | `Build` | `Packaging`

You should be able to add resources by clicking the button "`Add File/Folder...`".
After you have added a resource, you will get its path in the resulting WAR.

However, I strongly recommend you to use a build tool as [Maven](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Maven) (or [Ant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Maven)) to help you automate your build and put some structure in your application.